# How to combine Bar chart and data as table in High Charts

Tags: angular, highcharts

So basically I want to create a chart which has data grouping and separate counts displayed below the axis. Is this possible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4aAb.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Here is an example of combined bar chart in the HighChart documentation: [Doc Link](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/column-chart)

Comment: nop this is not what the solution looks like

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit lables using the [xAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) on the xAxis, like on this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-comparison)

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    max: 4,
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      animate: true,
      formatter: ctx => {
        let flag;

        countries.forEach(function(country) {
          if (country.name === ctx.value) {
            flag = country.flag;
          }
        });

        return `${flag.toUpperCase()}<br><span class="f32">
                    <span class="flag ${flag}"></span>
                </span>`;
      },
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center'
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/szxm8423/2/